# Raster Georeference

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I'm trying to georeference an image exported from Google earth via Raster > georeference but the problem when I click Raster menu, georeference doesn't appear. Would you please help me to display it?

Comment: Where did you read that it should be there and by default?

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled the GDAL Georeferencer plugin in the plugin dialog?

[image]

I see a "Georeferencer" option under my `Raster` menu. QGIS 3. I think QGIS 2.x was similar. Check the plugin list.

Comment: No, it's enabled but I can't find "Georeference" under raster menu.

Comment: I can confirm that 2.18 works the same way. Georeferencer must be enabled in plugin dialog, then it appears in raster menu.